# Add multiple selectors which contain html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at my source code. I want to add 3 `divs' selector into a variable and then put into another selector. My current code isn't working:

```
$(aoData).each(function(iKey, oValue){

            htmlContent.add($('<div/>', {
                class: 'col-sm-4',
                html: $('<a/>', {
                    class: 'app-block',
                    href: oValue.Link, 
                    html: "<h1>" + oValue.Name + "</h1><h2>" + oValue.Description + "</h2>"
                })
            }));

            i++;

            if(i > 2 || iKey+1 >= aoData.length){
                $('<row/>', {
                    html: htmlContent
                }).appendTo('#apps');
                i = 0;
                htmlContent = {};
            }

        });
```

Comment: What is `htmlContent`?

Comment: @dfsq before i declared it as string, array and object. no one worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `htmlContent` as an array and use `push` instead of `add` and it should work:

```
var htmlContent = [];

// ...

htmlContent.push($('<div/>', {
    class: 'col-sm-4',
    html: $('<a/>', {
        class: 'app-block',
        href: oValue.Link, 
        html: "<h1>" + oValue.Name + "</h1><h2>" + oValue.Description + "</h2>"
    })
}));
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4roqm0bv/

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe it. I thought i tried that too! My bloody mistake